# Spring-Data-Elasticsearch custom analyzer not getting imported

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

My settings.json:

```
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_whitespace_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "whitespace"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My Index Domain:

```
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.*;

@Document(indexName = "employeedb", type="employeeDetails")
@Setting(settingPath = "/elasticsearch/settings.json")
public class EmployeeDetailsIndex {

    @Id
    @Field(type = FieldType.Keyword, name = "empId", store = true) //store will store the original empId as well as the analyzed one
    private String empId;


    @Field(type = FieldType.Keyword, name = "name", analyzer = "my_whitespace_analyzer", searchAnalyzer = "my_whitespace_analyzer")
    private String name;

//Getters and Setters
}
```

Error that gets thrown:

failed to load elasticsearch nodes : org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchStatusException: Elasticsearch exception [type=mapper_parsing_exception, reason=Mapping definition for [name] has unsupported parameters:  [search_analyzer : my_whitespace_analyzer] [analyzer : my_whitespace_analyzer]]

I wanted to test custom analyzer in elastic search.

From the above error, it seems that the settings.json isn't getting loaded. I have correctly mapped settings.json to @Settings.
All of the tutorials online maps the settings.json using the @Settings annotation.

What may be the issue with this?

Is the JSON type incorrect?
I have tried with

Versions used:
Java: 1.8.0
Elastic Search: 6.8.15
Spring Boot: 2.2.8.RELSEASE
Spring-Data-Elasticsearch: 3.2.8.RELEASE

Answer (score 0):

The JSON you provide in the `@Setting` annotation must only contain the values for the setting, not the *setting* property itself:

```json
{
    "analysis": {
        "analyzer": {
            "my_whitespace_analyzer": {
                "tokenizer": "whitespace"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit 17.05.2023**:

Having a closer look:

1. You are using a pretty outdated version of Spring Data Elasticsearch. 3.2 is out of maintenance since October 2020; I don't know - and don't have the time to look it up) - if reading from a file was already implemented there without bugs. The tests I now did are with the current version.
2. document type were deprecated in Elasticsearch 6 and removed in Elasticsearch 7 (in the meantime Elasticsearch is at 8.7). So for Spring Data Elasticsearch 4+ you need to remove the `type=...` parameter from the `@Document` annotation.
3. Defining an analyzer for a field of type **keyword** makes no sense. Keyword fields are not analyzed. You need to change this to `FieldType.text`.
4. The analyzer specified in the JSON file is missing the *type*. But I don't know if this was already necessary in ES 6.

So with these two changes:

```json
{
  "analysis": {
    "analyzer": {
      "my_whitespace_analyzer": {
        "type": "custom",
        "tokenizer": "whitespace"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and

```java
@Document(indexName = "employeedb")
@Setting(settingPath = "/elasticsearch/settings.json")
public class EmployeeDetailsIndex {

    @Id
    @Field(type = FieldType.Keyword, name = "empId", store = true)
    //store will store the original empId as well as the analyzed one
    private String empId;


    @Field(type = FieldType.Text, name = "name", analyzer = "my_whitespace_analyzer", searchAnalyzer = "my_whitespace_analyzer")
    private String name;

// getter and setter
}
```

this runs without error in a sample application, creating the index with the correct settings.

Comment: I tried with this as well it still gives the same output :')

Comment: DId you delete the index and have it recreated? with the  hanged code?

Comment: see my edit above